# array picks only the last value to store

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops

The script below apparently uses the API documented at http://www.hasoffers.com/wiki/Offer:create. S the question has (at least) two parts: a) How to store more than one data set within an array. b) Does the API accept it....

---

When i run the script it only stores the last value inside 'data' how can i get it to store more data at once?

The code below has for example 2 values. one is caled LOLO and the other one is caled LELE.
The output shows only the value LELE.

this is the code.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$base = 'http://api.hasoffers.com/Api?';

$params = array(
'Format' => 'json'
,'Target' => 'Offer'
,'Method' => 'create'
,'Service' => 'HasOffers'
,'Version' => 2
,'NetworkId' => 'demo'
,'NetworkToken' => '....'
,'data' => array(
        'name' => 'LOLO'
        ,'description' => 'test'
        ,'offer_url' => 'http://google.nl'
        ,'preview_url' => 'http://google.nl'
        ,'expiration_date' => '08-08-2013'

        ,'name' => 'LELE'
        ,'description' => 'test'
        ,'offer_url' => 'http://google.nl'
        ,'preview_url' => 'http://google.nl'
        ,'expiration_date' => '08-08-2013' 
)
);

$url = $base . http_build_query( $params );

$result = file_get_contents( $url );


print_r( json_decode( $result) );
?>
```

and this is the output

```
[request] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Target] => Offer
        [Format] => json
        [Service] => HasOffers
        [Version] => 2
        [Method] => create
        [NetworkId] => demo
        [NetworkToken] => NETU2nzMw8AYS6EGgjFrjGR88GcSiF
        [data] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => LELE
                [description] => test
                [offer_url] => http://google.nl
                [preview_url] => http://google.nl
                [expiration_date] => 08-08-2013
            )

    )
```

Comment: you have array with only one element in it, and inside it key values are repeating so last one is remembered.

Comment: but when i run the script it shows me [0]=>... and [1]=>... how can i do this without getting this values becuz the API of Hasoffer platform only accept 'data'=>[name].. not 'data'=>[0]=>[name]

Comment: The answer could be (and having skimmed over the api documentation I think it is): You have to send two separate requests two create two separate offers.

Comment: does it work if you set name for this two arrays ('data' => array( 'first'=> array(
        'name' => 'LOLO'
        ,'description' => 'test'
        ,'offer_url' => 'http://google.nl'
        ,'preview_url' => 'http://google.nl'
        ,'expiration_date' => '08-08-2013'),
        'second' => array(
  'name' => 'LELE'
        ,'description' => 'test'
        ,'offer_url' => 'http://google.nl'
        ,'preview_url' => 'http://google.nl'
        ,'expiration_date' => '08-08-2013' 
       )
)) ?

Comment: no it doesn't work .. is it possible to set the request in some kind of loop for each array ? so that it loops every time with a new value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i did and it works

```
<?php

// Bestand openen
if (($file = fopen("test2.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    // Eerste rij van Excel als value gebruiken
    $header = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ";");


    // Een loop door Excel file
    while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {



            // combineer de eerste rij met de gegevens
            $combined = array_combine($header,$data);

            // Connectie maken met Hasoffers bij elke waarden
            $base = 'http://api.hasoffers.com/Api?';

            $params = array(
                'Format' => 'json'
                ,'Target' => 'Offer'
                ,'Method' => 'create'
                ,'Service' => 'HasOffers'
                ,'Version' => 2
                ,'NetworkId' => 'demo'
                ,'NetworkToken' => '.....'
                ,'data' => $combined
            );

            $url = $base . http_build_query( $params );

            $result = file_get_contents( $url );

            // Tijdelijk printen
            print_r( json_encode( $result) );
    }
}
?>
```

I've created a loop including a CSV file.
the problem was that it connected only once with hasoffer and that allowed only one value.

Answer (score 0):

```
'data' => array(
  array (
    'name' => 'LOLO',
    'description' => 'test',
    'offer_url' => 'http://google.nl',
    'preview_url' => 'http://google.nl'
    'expiration_date' => '08-08-2013'),
  array (
    'name' => 'LELE',
    'description' => 'test',
    'offer_url' => 'http://google.nl',
    'preview_url' => 'http://google.nl',
    'expiration_date' => '08-08-2013'))
```

Comment: Do you know this to work with http://www.hasoffers.com/wiki/Offer:create or is it a generic answer?

Comment: @VolkerK Just generic answer

Answer (score 0):

```
,'data' => array( array(
        'name' => 'LOLO'
        ,'description' => 'test'
        ,'offer_url' => 'http://google.nl'
        ,'preview_url' => 'http://google.nl'
        ,'expiration_date' => '08-08-2013'
        ),
        array(
        ,'name' => 'LELE'
        ,'description' => 'test'
        ,'offer_url' => 'http://google.nl'
        ,'preview_url' => 'http://google.nl'
        ,'expiration_date' => '08-08-2013' 
        )
)
```

You need to add it as a multi dimensional array or else it will overwrite the elements with same key. Please note the  `array (....)` addd inside your `array`

`array( array(`

Comment: Do you know this to work with http://www.hasoffers.com/wiki/Offer:create or is it a generic answer?

Comment: This is a generic answer, you need to specify like this for multi dimensional array in php

Answer (score 0):

**Or** you can store it in this way

```
$data = array();
$data[0] = array('name' => 'LELE'
    , 'description' => 'test'
    , 'offer_url' => 'http://google.nl'
    , 'preview_url' => 'http://google.nl'
    , 'expiration_date' => '08-08-2013'
);

$data[1] = array('name' => 'LOLO'
    , 'description' => 'test'
    , 'offer_url' => 'http://google.nl'
    , 'preview_url' => 'http://google.nl'
    , 'expiration_date' => '08-08-2013'
);

$params = array(
    'Format' => 'json'
    , 'Target' => 'Offer'
    , 'Method' => 'create'
    , 'Service' => 'HasOffers'
    , 'Version' => 2
    , 'NetworkId' => 'demo'
    , 'NetworkToken' => 'NETU2nzMw8AYS6EGgjFrjGR88GcSiF'
    , 'data' => $data
);

print_r($params);
```

// Output

```
Array
(
    [Format] => json
    [Target] => Offer
    [Method] => create
    [Service] => HasOffers
    [Version] => 2
    [NetworkId] => demo
    [NetworkToken] => NETU2nzMw8AYS6EGgjFrjGR88GcSiF
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => LELE
                    [description] => test
                    [offer_url] => http://google.nl
                    [preview_url] => http://google.nl
                    [expiration_date] => 08-08-2013
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => LOLO
                    [description] => test
                    [offer_url] => http://google.nl
                    [preview_url] => http://google.nl
                    [expiration_date] => 08-08-2013
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Do you know this to work with http://www.hasoffers.com/wiki/Offer:create or is it a generic answer?

Answer (score 0):

**a) How to store more than one data set within an array.**

```
$fixed_params = array(
 'Format' => 'json'
 ,'Target' => 'Offer'
 ,'Method' => 'create'
 ,'Service' => 'HasOffers'
 ,'Version' => 2
 ,'NetworkId' => 'demo'
 ,'NetworkToken' => '....'
);

$offer_data = array(
array(
        'name' => 'LOLO'
        ,'description' => 'test'
        ,'offer_url' => 'http://google.nl'
        ,'preview_url' => 'http://google.nl'
        ,'expiration_date' => '08-08-2013'
),
array(
        'name' => 'LELE'
        ,'description' => 'test'
        ,'offer_url' => 'http://google.nl'
        ,'preview_url' => 'http://google.nl'
        ,'expiration_date' => '08-08-2013' 
 )
);

// store all results here 
$result = array();

// iterates two times since $offer_data has two elements.
foraech ($offer_data as $offern => $data ){
 // store offer's data into fixed_params['data'] element.
 $fixed_params['data'] = $data;

 $url = $base . http_build_query( $fixed_params );

 $result[] =  json_decode( file_get_contents( $url ));
}

print_r($result);
```

**b) Does the API accept it....**

As I understand the API, it accepts only one create at time. See http://www.hasoffers.com/wiki/Offer:create it says: *Creates a new offer.*